# Vim plugin for manual automatic indentation

Tags: vim, plugins, indentation

I want Vim to automatically repeat exactly all the matching symbols from beginnings of last two lines on every linebreak.

for example, consider that i am currently on the third line:

```
> tab space This line is ignored
> tab space tab This is line #1. Lorem.
> tab space tab This is line #2. Ipsum.
```

If i press `o` --- or hit [Enter] in insert mode --- i want to go to a new line, automatically insert following text:

```
> tab space tab This is line #
```

and enter insert mode at the end of the line.

Is there a plugin/script/vimrc line to do such a thing?

(such a thing is really useful for editing multiline comments etc.)

Comment: If I understand this right, this is a rather obscure use case. Of course, you can implement this with a few lines of Vimscript. But I doubt something like that already exists, and asking for plugins unfortunately is off-topic here, anyway. Why don't you try to implement this yourself and add any parts you're struggling with to your question later?!

Comment: Hi toldeng why `tab space tab` ? why mix both formats?
Anyway You could just record a macro which will double the line and delete everything after the `#` something like `yypf#lC`